# Resetting sitemap warnings in Webmaster Tools

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitemap, crawl-errors, link-submission

Back in the day when I was updating my website and had errors, Google Webmaster Tools took note of it and gave my sitemap files warnings.

Now I decided to start over new again by uploading brand new sitemaps with today's date stamped on them, and yet I still get the same warnings dated from weeks ago as follows:

> When we tested a sample of the URLs from your Sitemap, we found that some of the URLs were unreachable. Please check your webserver for possible misconfiguration, as these errors may be caused by a server error (such as a 5xx error) or a network error between Googlebot and your server. All reachable URLs will still be submitted.
>
> Some URLs in the Sitemap have a high response time.
> Some URLs listed in this Sitemap have a high response time. This may indicate a problem with your server or with the content of the page.

I have fixed these issues now, but I don't know how to delete the warnings and make Google re-evaluate my website again. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I have a similar problem not having to do with my sitemap itself. These things just seem to hang around forever so far- quite a few months now. If someone has an answer, I am interested! One up-vote!!

Answer (score 2):

When you have fixed the issues with your sitemap. Click on your sitemap in webmaster tools to view the errors/warnings and there is a red button at the top that says "Resubmit Sitemap" Click this. This will tell Google to re-crawl your sitemap. And if you have indeed fixed the issues correctly Google will remove them its self.

But you know, these things take time. Though Google is significantly faster at this than Bing and Yandex. Sometimes, it does take weeks