# Which is faster for sitemap submission: ping or submit via search console?

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitemap

Previously I asked a question about marking sitemap warnings as fixed here:

[Resetting sitemap warnings in Webmaster Tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78152/resetting-sitemap-warnings-in-webmaster-tools)

I look in my account today and find such warnings and errors are always outdated, and now I want to know which is the fastest method of telling google that I made changes and that all links are correct.

Should I try using the ping URL at google to re-submit my sitemap or do I have to use Google Search Console? Which is the fastest in terms of overall sitemap submission and processing?

I'm asking because I don't want to see random warnings and errors stay in my Google Search console account for however many days it feels like doing it when I make changes to my website. I want to see those warnings and errors gone asap.

Oh, and the number of URLs in the sitemap are about 12,000.

Comment: If I have you right, the notices in the Google Search Console sitemap thingy will stick around. For my sitemap, these are old and very annoying. But also not a problem. Search Console still tells me that my site is not mobile friendly from well over a year ago when it is perfectly mobile friendly. It is bad UX.

Comment: BTW- I do not think Google offers a ping, at least they did not when I looked quite some time ago. I would think that the Search Console would be preferred. You do not have to resubmit sitemaps as long as your sitemap keeps the same name. Google will check it periodically. Also, take what Google says about your sitemap with a lot of salt. Errors are one thing, however, the pages indexed as an example, will not reflect reality most of the time.

Comment: I agree with closetnoc, If I was there then I will not going to spend my most of time on that. :)

Comment: According to stackoverflow.com and my test, this link seems to work: http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=<insert URL here> and I get: "Sitemap Notification Received

 Your Sitemap has been successfully added to our list of Sitemaps to crawl. If this is the first time you are notifying Google about this Sitemap, please add it via http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ so you can track its status. Please note that we do not add all submitted URLs to our index, and we cannot make any predictions or guarantees about when or if they will appear."

Answer (score 1):

Warnings in the Google search console stay there even after the issue has been resolved. As for the fastest way to report the update to Google it doesn't matter whether you use the ping URL or resubmit the whole sitemap as functionally they work the same in that they extract the URL's and add them to the queue to be re-indexed when they can be. In the case of the ping URL this is useful for submitting a single updated page to the queue for re-crawling whereas submitting an updated sitemap can be useful if you have made a large number of changes to your site and added additional pages. The important thing to note here is that there is no strict requirement to even do either of these as Google will automatically re-index your site as often as it algorithmically believes is necessary to detect when changes have been made to your site. As an example a site I manage gets re-crawled by Google on a daily basis, and yet another site I manage which does not change as frequently only gets re-crawled once every 1-2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The errors stay in the list of Search Console even after you clear them for a few days regardless of what you do.

I have used the Search Console fetch & submit a link to notify Google of a change in a page (for example Title or Description change) and have seen it updated in the SERP within the hour.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of actual processing, both probably the same.

But a 'ping' wont clear the warnings in the console. Only manual re-submitting via the console will flush the warnings.